# jquery alternate for list sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I have a list, what User can do is drag and drop items in a list, But these all items are complicated (lables and tinymce instance in all items) so I dont want to actual move the items, but want to move content of a items
Suppose I have li as

```
1. <div id = "div1">abcd</div>
2. <div id = "div2">efgh</div>
3. <div id = "div3">xyz</div>
```

if i use sortable and suppose user drag drop and changed position like

```
1. <div id = "div2">efgh</div>
2. <div id = "div1">abcd</div>
3. <div id = "div3">xyz</div>
```

you can see here actual componant is moved. I want It may be as

```
1. <div id = "div1">efgh</div>
2. <div id = "div2">abcd</div>
3. <div id = "div3">xyz</div>
```

although refreshPositions is not working in my case may be tinyMCE is responsible for this 
Please tell me if there is any way

Answer (score 0):

yah I got the fix, 
after stoping drag (on stop event of sortable) I cancel the sortable feture by $(selector).sortable("cancel")
then i fetch actual data of draged item and droped item and swap these datas 
then i refresh my view,  its working :)